# parsing xml into jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

i am parsing xml in jquery. i want to see one line of symbols when it runs by "alert()".

here is xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<charlist>
    <list>
        <title>symbol1</title>
        <chr><![CDATA[√,∽, ∝, ∵, ∫, ∬, ∈, ∋, ⊆]]></chr>
    </list>
    <list>
        <title>symbol2</title>
        <chr><![CDATA[①, ②, ③, ④, ⑤, ⑥, ⑦, ⑧]]></chr>
    </list>
    <list>
        <title>symbol3</title>
        <chr><![CDATA[㉠, ㉡, ㉢, ㉣, ㉤, ㉥, ㉦, ㉧]]></chr>
    </list>
    <list>
        <title>symbol4</title>
        <chr><![CDATA[㎕, ㎖, ㎗, ℓ, ㎘, ㏄, ㎣, ㎤]]></chr>
    </list>
</charlist>
```

this is jquery i made.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "XMLFile1.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        $(xml).find('list').each(function () {
            var title = $(this).find("title").text();
            var chr = $(this).find("chr").text();
            alert(chr);
        });
    }
});
```

three lines appear after running this. "√,∽, ∝, ∵, ∫, ∬, ∈, ∋, ⊆" and then, ㉠, ㉡, ㉢, ㉣, ㉤, ㉥, ㉦, ㉧ and then, ㎕, ㎖, ㎗, ℓ, ㎘, ㏄, ㎣, ㎤.
i just want to see one line that I choose in jquery by array.
for example. If i put like "alert(chr[1]), second line comes out like ㉠, ㉡, ㉢, ㉣, ㉤, ㉥, ㉦, ㉧. only one line appears by "alert".
anyone can help me with this problem???

Comment: Are you saying that you want to put those lines of characters in an array so that you can display them individually?

Comment: It appears you asked an almost identical question on the 13th.  You should delete one of them.

Comment: yes, i want to display only one line that i put a number on "alert(chr[])".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, the following example should help you understand how to build the array from your xml:

```
 var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
<charlist>\
    <list>\
        <title>symbol1</title>\
        <chr><![CDATA[√,∽, ∝, ∵, ∫, ∬, ∈, ∋, ⊆]]></chr>\
    </list>\
    <list>\
        <title>symbol2</title>\
        <chr><![CDATA[①, ②, ③, ④, ⑤, ⑥, ⑦, ⑧]]></chr>\
    </list>\
    <list>\
        <title>symbol3</title>\
        <chr><![CDATA[㉠, ㉡, ㉢, ㉣, ㉤, ㉥, ㉦, ㉧]]></chr>\
    </list>\
    <list>\
        <title>symbol4</title>\
        <chr><![CDATA[㎕, ㎖, ㎗, ℓ, ㎘, ㏄, ㎣, ㎤]]></chr>\
    </list>\
</charlist>';

var parsed = $.parseXML(xml);

// declare the array
var chr = new Array();

// build the array by looping through the list elements
$(parsed).find('list').each(function(i,listElement){
    chr[i] = listElement.getElementsByTagName('chr')[0].textContent; 
});​

// will give an alert box with the string content of the chr element in the the second list element, which is actually "①, ②, ③, ④, ⑤, ⑥, ⑦, ⑧"
alert(chr[1]);
```

Comment: i think you understand what i want, but it still appears all lines.

Comment: line means like "㎕, ㎖, ㎗, ℓ, ㎘, ㏄, ㎣, ㎤". i am seeing three boxes like first, "√,∽, ∝, ∵, ∫, ∬, ∈, ∋, ⊆", second ①, ②, ③, ④, ⑤, ⑥, ⑦, ⑧, third ㉠, ㉡, ㉢, ㉣, ㉤, ㉥, ㉦, ㉧, forth ㎕, ㎖, ㎗, ℓ, ㎘, ㏄, ㎣, ㎤. i only want to see one that i put a number on "alert(chr[]).